# When do we need to put semicolon after curly brackets? i.e.: "};"

Tags: java, android

In Java, semicolon comes after curly brackets only for arrays and enum.
But I found it different in Android coding. For example why there is a **;** after **}** in the following code:

```
Thread myThread=new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // something
    }
};
```

Comment: Android is still Java. You just made a `new Thread();`. What are you confused about?

Comment: And you *can* do `if (bool) {};`, but no-one really ever does

Comment: A `;` is required after every *statement* and in a few other places such as field/variable declarations. Class declarations (including those for anonymous classes, although such can be found within statements) are not statements. Method declarations are not statements. Code blocks (often following conditional operators) are not statements.

Comment: @cricket_007 @user2864740 `new Thread() { }` is just a block, so why it is ended with `;`

Comment: @Faramarz it's not a block.  `Thread myThread = ...` has to end with a semicolon whether there's an anonymous class in it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once."

[Java - Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Instead of doing something like this:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // something
    }
}
...
Thread myThread= new MyThread();
```

You can sorten your code by doing it this other way using anonymous classes.

```
Thread myThread=new Thread(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
      // something
   }
};
```

Comment: What does this have to do with semi-colons?

Comment: anonymous class when declared and instantiated at the same time become part of the statement

Comment: but you can do for example `myObj.call(new Foo() {....});` and there is no `;` after ending `}`, semicolon is because it is `variable = expression` statement, so you have to add `;` after `expression`

Comment: Yes, but where does you statement end?

Comment: Glad, I could help. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in the most general way possible, a semicolon is needed after a closing brace **when the brace is part of an expression, and that expression appears at the end of a statement which would normally end with a semicolon**.

In your example, the closing brace is part of a [class instance creation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), which is used in a variable declaration statement. A variable declaration statement always ends with a semicolon, regardless of whether the initializer expression happens to end with a closing brace.

Another example is an [array initializer expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

```java
int[] nums = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

A third example is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4):

```java
Function<String, Integer> lengthGetter = s -> { return s.length(); };
```

What all these examples have in common is that the braces are part of an expression, i.e. they are code which results in a value that can be assigned to a variable, passed as an argument, etc. The statements containing these expressions require semicolons at the end, whether or not the expression ends with a closing brace; it is the *statement* which requires the semicolon, not the expression which forms part of that statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a book example of an anonymous class which in turn requires a semicolon since you're really still instantiating the Thread class.

Answer (score 0):

Because the code is still of the form `variable = statement;`

The code block is essentially extending the `Thread` class and making an in-line anonymous one.

Since this is Android, I assume you've made a `new View.OnClickListener() {}` at some point, right?

Same idea. Move the listener out of the `setOnClickListener` method.

```
View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {  }
}; // <-- semi-colon

button.setOnClickListener(click);
```